# Tree construction from a node string (Can't understand this Haskell code)

Tags: haskell

I was trying to learn Haskell by 99 Haskell problems and bumped into "4 Problem 70". It's about "Tree construction from a node string". (the description is [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/70B_to_73))

And I just don't understand the last solution [there](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/70).

> The exercise was really designed for Prolog, and calls for a bidirectional predicate. The closest thing to that, in Haskell, is a class! This is really a parsing/pretty-printing solution, with the names to match. Rather than trying to work with strings and a special "up" character (which won't really work at the type level), we use lists of explicit instructions. The requested predicate is BuildTree.

```
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies,
         FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances,
         DataKinds, PolyKinds #-}

import Data.Tree
data Instr c = Up | Down c

class ParseTree str t '[]
  => BuildTree (str :: [Instr c]) (t :: Tree c) | str -> t, t -> str
instance ParseTree str t '[]
     => BuildTree str t
```

> We use two helpers to implement it:

```
class ParseTree (str :: [Instr c]) (t :: Tree c) (rem :: [Instr c])
            | str -> t rem, t rem -> str
class ParseForest (str :: [Instr c]) (ts :: [Tree c]) (rem :: [Instr c])
            | str -> ts rem, ts rem -> str

instance ParseTree ('Down c ': 'Up ': r) ('Node c '[]) r
instance ParseForest ('Down d ': is) (t ': ts) r
     => ParseTree ('Down c ': 'Down d ': is) ('Node c (t ': ts)) r

instance ParseForest ('Up ': is) '[] is
instance ( ParseTree ('Down c ': is) t r
     , ParseForest r ts r')
     => ParseForest ('Down c ': is) (t ': ts) r'
```

And I ghci this code and can't find a function ready to use.

> The requested predicate is BuildTree.

Does that mean I have to write this predicate?

Thank you for help!

Comment: This is silly code that parses strings at compile-time within the type system. If you're a beginner, I'd recommend ignoring this example for now.

Comment: This solution abuses the type system so to compute the required function at the type level. It does not produce a working program. It does produce some definitions such that, if one asks GHCi _the type_ of a carefully crafted expression (without evaluating it!), the resulting _type_ will include the wanted answer in some format. Basically, it is a hack to force the type inference engine to do the job we want. It is more like a joke than an intended solution. If you are learning Haskell, this is a clever hack that you should ignore.

Comment: I see it now. It's really a clever hack. I will find something else to learn. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I agree with the comments:  don't try to understand this "solution" until you've been using Haskell for a few years.  For the sake of completeness, though, here's how to use it...

This solution is implemented as a "type-level computation" that takes place at compile time.  I'm a little surprised the author didn't provide an explanation of how to use it, since it's far from obvious.

There may be a better way, but here's one that works.  First:

- Add `TypeOperator` to the list of extensions -- I couldn't get it to compile under GHC 8.0.2 without that.
- Add an `import Data.Proxy`

Then, at the bottom, add:

```
data Nodes = A | B | C | D | E
u = (Proxy :: BuildTree str (Node A [Node B '[], Node C '[]]) => Proxy str)
```

This defines some constructors for node labels that get lifted to types by the `DataKinds` extension.  We then define the symbol `u` as a value of type `str` subject to a constraint based on the "predicate" `BuildTree str t` where `t` is the tree.  Note that the *value* of `u` isn't important (and in fact it's the boring value "`Proxy`"); it's `u`'s *type* that's important...

Haskell's type inference will calculate the type of `str` which we can display in GHCi like so:

```
> :t u
u :: Proxy '['Down 'A, 'Down 'B, 'Up, 'Down 'C, 'Up, 'Up]
>
```

Similarly, adding:

```
v = (Proxy :: BuildTree (['Down 'A, 'Down 'B, 'Up, 'Down 'C, 'Up, 'Up]) t 
    => Proxy t)
```

at the bottom gives us the reverse transformation:

```
> :t v
v :: Proxy ('Node 'A '['Node 'B '[], 'Node 'C '[]])
>
```

Note that the `Proxy` is used here just to allow us to assign the type to an object.  Without the proxy, we're trying to assign `u` and `v` to types with a kind other than `*` (i.e., the kind of concrete types), and that isn't allowed.

Comment: Oh! So the constraint is the predicate BuildTree str t. And Haskell's type inference will calculate the type. And the answer is in the type. I see. Thx!